# Create PDF with all possible filter values ( or only specific filter values)

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm using PowerBI desktop, and have setup the page to be Letter size.
I have a dropdown for State & Month, and a card with sales data.
I need to create a PDF report: each page of this report needs to be a separate month and state.

How do i create this without having to manually change the dropdown values and press Ctrl+P every time?

I've attached pictures for reference
Thank You

[image: This is my PowerBI Desktop report page]

[image: This is how the PDF is generated currently]

Answer (score 0):

you can use paginated report
then you need to  groupe  your data in the report, you could use the page break option in your group. This means when you save it to PDF each group will be on it's own page.